# d3.time.interval.range() in d3 doesn't return equally spaced intervals

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using the following function to create equally spaced time intervals:

```
d3.time.second.range(new Date(1444717315000), new Date(1444717615000), 38)
```

```js
var _text = "";
d3.time.second.range(new Date(1444717315000), new Date(1444717615000), 38).forEach(function(d) {
  
  _text = _text + d.toString();
 _text = _text + '<br>';
  
  
})

document.getElementById("timearray").innerHTML = _text
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="timearray">
```

This is specified in d3 API as:

> #### # interval.range(start, stop[, step])
>
> Returns every time interval after or equal to start and before stop. If step is specified, then every step'th interval will be returned, based on the interval number (such as day of month for d3.time.day). For example, a step of 2 will return the 1st, 3rd, 5th etc. of the month with d3.time.day.

While I expect it  to return the resulting array equally spaced at 38 seconds something like:

```
0: Tue Oct 13 2015 11:52:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
1: Tue Oct 13 2015 11:52:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
2: Tue Oct 13 2015 11:53:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
3: Tue Oct 13 2015 11:53:54 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
..
..
```

What I'm getting is (not equally spaced):

```
0: Tue Oct 13 2015 11:52:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
1: Tue Oct 13 2015 11:52:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
2: Tue Oct 13 2015 11:53:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
3: Tue Oct 13 2015 11:53:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
4: Tue Oct 13 2015 11:54:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
5: Tue Oct 13 2015 11:54:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
6: Tue Oct 13 2015 11:55:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
7: Tue Oct 13 2015 11:55:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
8: Tue Oct 13 2015 11:56:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
9: Tue Oct 13 2015 11:56:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Is this usage wrong? Or does the API mean something else? Do we have a different function for this?

Comment: Pragmatically, you could just take the starting point (1444717315000) and then just add 38000 till you hit/exceed the end point...

Comment: The example in the documentation talks about every nth day, particularly every second day _of the month_.  In your case you are not returning values spaced at 38 seconds, you are returning _every 38th second of the minute_, of which there is only one in each minute. Try it with an interval of less than 30 seconds and you will see multiple values for each minute, for example a value of 10 will give you all of the available 10th seconds in each minute, which, if you start on a zero second boundary, will be 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 0, 10, ....  Seems like by design to me...

Answer (score 1):

d3.time is respecting the structure of the Date object, not just treating it as a decimal number, which is one way to describe what you are looking for I guess.

To achieve what you want, therefore, you do not want to use d3.time, but just generate a series of numbers which are 38000 msec apart.

```js
var _text = "";
d3.range(1444717320000, 1444717615000, 38000)
.map(function(t){return new Date(t)})
.forEach(function(d) {
  
  _text = _text + d.toString();
 _text = _text + '<br>';
  
  
})

document.getElementById("timearray").innerHTML = _text
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="timearray">
```